# qemu is crashing with docker chromium for mac m1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, chromium, qemu

I'm trying to generate a docker image to run chromium on M1 and attach puppeteer.

To generate it and push it on my private docker hub, I use github actions:

My github action

```yaml
name: build-web-builder-docker

on:
    workflow_dispatch:
        inputs:
        # no inputs

jobs:
    build-docker:
        name: build-docker

        # not using self-hosted-org because this needs to run docker in privileged mode (see setup-builder step)
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: setup-quemu
              id: qemu
              uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
            - name: available-platforms
              run: echo ${{ steps.qemu.outputs.platforms }}

            - name: setup-builder
              run: |
                  docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all
                  echo "${{secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}}" | docker login -u ${{secrets.DOCKERHUB_USER}} --password-stdin
                  docker buildx create --name mybuilder --use
                  docker buildx ls

            - name: read-version
              id: read-version # needed to read the step output in the next step
              working-directory: ./docker
              run: echo ::set-output name=DOCKER_TAG::$(cat version | xargs) # using xargs to trim surrounding whitespace

            - name: build-docker
              working-directory: ./docker
              run: |
                  echo "TAG=${{ steps.read-version.outputs.DOCKER_TAG }}"
                  docker buildx build -t "my/private-repo:${{ steps.read-version.outputs.DOCKER_TAG }}" --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 . --push
```

And this is my `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 debian:unstable-20211011-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    apt-utils \
    locales \
    curl \
    git \
    unzip \
    procps

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    fonts-liberation \
    libayatana-appindicator3-1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libc6 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgcc1 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    lsb-release \
    wget \
    xdg-utils

# setup locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install chromium -fy


# install nodejs and related stuff
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    nodejs \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make
RUN npm install -g yarn@^1.22.15

ENV TZ UTC

CMD ["/usr/bin/google-chrome", \
    # flags from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/Launcher.js
    "--disable-background-networking", \
    "--disable-background-timer-throttling", \
    "--disable-breakpad", \
    "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection", \
    "--disable-default-apps", \
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage", \
    "--disable-extensions", \
    "--disable-features=site-per-process", \
    "--disable-hang-monitor", \
    "--disable-popup-blocking", \
    "--disable-prompt-on-repost", \
    "--disable-sync", \
    "--disable-translate", \
    "--metrics-recording-only", \
    "--no-first-run", \
    "--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", \
    "--enable-automation", \
    "--password-store=basic", \
    "--use-mock-keychain", \
    "--headless", \
    "--hide-scrollbars", \
    # Disable sandbox mode
    "--no-sandbox", \
    # Avoids font rendering differences between headless/headfull
    "--font-render-hinting=none", \
    # Expose port 9222 for remote debugging
    "--remote-debugging-port=9222", \
    "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", \
    "--ignore-certificate-errors" \
    ]
```

The generation of the image works, but when I try to execute the image on my M1 this happens:

my `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    docker-chromium:
        platform: "linux/amd64"
        image: my/private-repo:version
        ports:
            - '9223:9222'
```

And the output I get if I enter the container and try to execute chromium:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
[0624/183808.715658:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0624/183808.722735:ERROR:bus.cc(398)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[0624/183808.730740:ERROR:file_path_watcher_inotify.cc(329)] inotify_init() failed: Function not implemented (38)

DevTools listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9222/devtools/browser/d4ccad21-67b3-4b0c-86a5-aafb98052cb4
qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
[0624/183808.891939:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0624/183808.895531:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183808.895708:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0624/183808.945000:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(474)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
[0624/183809.119221:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183809.119287:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0624/183809.127363:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(474)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
[0624/183809.159148:INFO:render_frame_host_impl.cc(11505)] RenderFrameHostImpl::MaybeGenerateCrashReport url = , status = 5, exit_code = 1002
[0624/183809.171432:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183809.171993:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0624/183809.185157:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(474)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
[0624/183809.204684:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183809.204793:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
[0624/183809.216082:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183809.216159:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[0624/183809.223755:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(474)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
[0624/183809.230447:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=1002
[0624/183809.230543:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1277)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[0624/183809.230650:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(451)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
qemu: uncaught target signal 5 (Trace/breakpoint trap) - core dumped
Trace/breakpoint trap
root@5bb7c7d3c7f4:/# qemu: unknown option 'type=utility'
```

What's going on? Why isn't it running?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when i used chromium on my m1.
On amd64 architecture everything is fine. I have been use nextools/chromium(https://github.com/nextools/images/tree/master/chromium) as a base and slightly modify them by adding `libglfw3-dev` && `libgles2-mesa-dev`. Here the result

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ARG VERSION
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    # https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/319
    && apt-get install --yes apt-utils 2>&1 | grep -v "debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed" \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
    dumb-init \
    fontconfig \
    libglfw3-dev \
    libgles2-mesa-dev \
    chromium-browser=${VERSION}\* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

VOLUME ["/home/chromium/.fonts"]

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/chromium-browser", \
    "--disable-background-networking", \
    "--disable-background-timer-throttling", \
    "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows", \
    "--disable-renderer-backgrounding", \
    "--disable-breakpad", \
    "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection", \
    "--disable-default-apps", \
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage", \
    "--disable-extensions", \
    "--disable-gpu", \
    "--disable-popup-blocking", \
    "--disable-prompt-on-repost", \
    "--disable-sync", \
    "--disable-translate", \
    "--headless", \
    "--hide-scrollbars", \
    "--ignore-certificate-errors", \
    "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list", \
    "--ignore-ssl-errors", \
    "--metrics-recording-only", \
    "--mute-audio", \
    "--no-first-run", \
    "--no-sandbox", \
    "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", \
    "--remote-debugging-port=9222", \
    "--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", \
    "--user-data-dir=/home/chromium/"]
```

Now arm64 works fine.